# Using functions for a particular hook eg-admin_menu

Tags: wordpress

I am new to developing a plugin for Wordpress .
I read some code on codex for developing Administration menus .
Basically

1. I used a admin_menu hook.
2. Then I added a top level menu by using add_menu_page.
3. Then a submenu to the top level menu by using add_submenu_page.
4. So what we are doing is interacting with admin_menu hook function to add functionality before the admin panel is loaded .
5. I got the function add_menu_page and add_submenu_page from Codex but I want to know which other functions I can use for adding more functionality to this particular hook.
6. I am searching for reference to functions that i can use with any particular hooks to create a plugin.
7. I find this the approach that I should use , is there and other approach that anyone can advise .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two great resources:

http://hitchhackerguide.com/function-filter-action-index/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API